# fragment in view pager generate fatal error on activity restart

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have an activity that show data stored in database in a view pager organized in fragments.

When the adapter init the View Pager it call a method in each fragment to pass the id of the database entry to retrive and show:

```
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                firstFragment = Fragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 1");
                firstFragment.setID(ctx, id);
                return firstFragment;
            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                secondFragment = Fragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
                secondFragment.setID(ctx, id);
                return secondFragment;
            case 2: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                thirdtFragment = Fragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 3");
                thirdtFragment.setID(context, id);
                return thirdtFragment;

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

when the method onCreateView of the fragment get called it retrive the data from the database and init all the view displaying the data to the user:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    DataManager dataManager = new DataManager(mContext);
    DataModel data = dataManager.getData(mID);
    .....
```

All seems to work fine except when the user restart the app that was for example paused when inside this activity: when the activity got restarted I get a fatal error accessing the data, as if the private variable (of the fragment) containing the ID of the data got deleted from the garbage collector.

Is my approach correct? How can I prevent the error generated when the activity get restarted?

Comment: Can you please share the logcat?

Comment: I have a possible approach to this issue; let me give it as an answer so you can try it;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During `onPause` and `onResume` Fragment and Activity is managed by android so you may not retrieve the member variables so to overcome this problem on your Fragment's `newInstance` method use something like

```
public static Fragment newInstance(int id, String page){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("page", page);
    bundle.putInt("ID", page);
    setArguments(bundle);
}
```

and on your `onCreateView` callback use something like

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    int mID = getArguments().getInt("ID");
    DataManager dataManager = new DataManager(mContext);
    DataModel data = dataManager.getData(mID);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I approached my problem by doing the following:

- Create a view pager that has a list of Fragments and their respective titles. This view pager adapter should have a method to add fragments to the list. Here is my code:

  ```
  public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
     private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
     private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
     private int mItemId;

     public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, int id) {
        super(manager);
        mItemId = id;
     }

     @Override
     public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
     }

     @Override
     public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
     }

     public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("itemId", mItemId);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
     }

     @Override
     public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
     }}
  ```
- Now, inside your Fragment, you can extract the bundle extra which can help you when reading some data from your database for example if it is an id for table column. This could be your fragment class:

  ```
  public class InfoFragment extends Fragment {

      private Activity mActivity;

      private CustomerDbObject customer;
      private int customerId;

      public InfoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
      }

      @Override
      public void onAttach(Context ctx){
         super.onAttach(ctx);

         if (ctx instanceof Activity){
            this.mActivity = (Activity) ctx;
         }

         customerId = getArguments().getInt("itemId");

         Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(ctx);

         RealmQuery<Customer> query = realm.where(Customer.class);

         query = query.equalTo("account_id", customerId);

         customer = query.findFirst();
     }

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customer_fragment_info, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        return view;
    }}
  ```
- With these two pieces in place, what we need now is our activity that will display the viewpager with tabs! Remember, it is inside this same activity that we provide the extra (itemId) to the viewpager instance then the viewpager will pass it to the fragment in that order.

  ```
   public class CustomerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

       private int mSelectedCustomer = 5; //this value could be extracted for an intent that is passed from a Recyclerviewer etc

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_details);
           Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
           setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

           getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

           final ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
           setupViewPager(mViewPager);

           TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
           tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


           tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
           @Override
           public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

               mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
           }

           @Override
           public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

           }

           @Override
           public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

           }
      });

      }

      private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
         ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), mSelectedCustomer);
         adapter.addFrag(new InfoFragment(), getString(R.string.info_tab));
      }

  }
  ```

Now that we have all the pieces together, the important extra (data) being passed around should always be available to the Fragment through the viewpager adapter which gets it subsequently from the activity.

When I tested this, it worked and I hope it works for you as well. Please let me know how it goes!!